# How to use negative value in primeng p-slider?

Tags: angular, primeng

I use `p-slider` component of primeng ( version `^4.1.3` ).

I want p-slider's range is [-100,100].

My html code like as below :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="my form-inline">
   <input type="number" 
          class="form-control input-sm"
          min="-100" 
          max="100"
          [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent[0]" 
          name="filter.priceEditingPercent[0]" />
   -
   <input type="number" 
          class="form-control input-sm"
          min="-100"
          max="100"
          [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent[1]"
          name="filter.priceEditingPercent[1]" />

   &nbsp;{{l('PriceChangePercent')}}
  </label>

   <p-slider [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent"
             name="filter.priceEditingPercent"
             [range]="true">
   </p-slider>
</div>
```

My typeScript code like as below:

```
export class ItemPriceEditingComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {

    filter = {
        priceEditingPercent: [-100, 100]
    }

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        super(injector);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

I initialize filter.priceEditingPercent with [-100,100], but p-slider not render correctly. Negative values not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with use [max] and [min] inputs of p-slider component. I set -100 to [min]'s value   and set 100 to [max]'s value in HTML.

My correct html code like as below :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="my form-inline">
   <input type="number" 
          class="form-control input-sm"
          min="-100" 
          max="100"
          [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent[0]" 
          name="filter.priceEditingPercent[0]" />
   -
   <input type="number" 
          class="form-control input-sm"
          min="-100"
          max="100"
          [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent[1]"
          name="filter.priceEditingPercent[1]" />

   &nbsp;{{l('PriceChangePercent')}}
  </label>

   <p-slider [(ngModel)]="filter.priceEditingPercent"
             name="filter.priceEditingPercent"
             [range]="true"
             [min]="-100"
             [max]="100">
   </p-slider>
</div>
```